# Read new emails with office-js or similar to Google Apps Script's Trigger feature in office-js

Tags: outlook, office365, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I want to run a script when I receive a new email in Outlook for Office365. Is there any solution in [office-js]?

Instead of checking to receive new emails, I can read new emails every minute and run the script. In Google Apps Script (GAS), there is the [Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) that you can run a script every minute. Is there a similar feature in [office-js]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook web add-ins currently work only in the context of an item. So, `OfficeJS` doesn't provide built-in mechanisms for handling incoming items like VSTO does using the `NewMailEx` event. You may consider using Graph API, see [Use the Microsoft Graph API to get change notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph-rest-1.0) for more information.

Comment: Confirm this is the correct answer. 

We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our Tech Community Page. Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process.

aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions